# Random_shuffle alternative in C++Builder6

Tags: c++, arrays, random, c++builder, c++builder-6

As the title says, I'm trying to find a method to shuffle an array. C++Builder doesn't seem to have `random_shuffle()` and I don't know how to do it.

I can't find much about this program on google. To be more specific, I'm trying to do a memory matching game that has 16 pairs. I tried implementing something to give each card a random position (position 0, 1, 2, .. etc) but I don't know how to do it without having a value duplicated.

So the easiest method I see is creating an array `a[]={0,1,2,...31}` and shuffling the values somehow. Is it possible to do anything like this? If not, do I have any alternatives?

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: When your compiler is so old that is does not *yet* support a function deprecated in '14 and removed in '17, you know it's time to update.

Comment: Problem is, this is a school project, so I can't really use any other programs. I'm frustrated about having to use a weird and old program, but what can I do.

Comment: There are implementations detailed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).  You could write your own version using those.

Comment: fisher-yates shuffle is very easy to implement - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: CBuilder 6 appears to have _random_shuffle_ in the _algorithm_ header.

Comment: @DBBaxter yes, it does. I can confirm that (I use BCB6 at work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard algorithm to shuffle an array is the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  That is easy to implement and there are a number of examples on the web.  However, if you are learning then it would be a good idea to program it from scratch rather than blindly copy someone else's code.

Comment: Thanks !:) I managed to implement the Fisher-Yates algorithm and it's actually better than random_shuffle, since I have to make the game in OOP and make my own classes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

> The C++ Builder doesn't seem to have random_shuffle()

Yes, it does.  Make sure you have `#include <algorithm>` in your code.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks! It indeed works with the #include <algorithm.h>. Is there any way I can ask you some (short)questions about c++ builder? I'm struggling with some of its functions and can't find anything on the internet. I'm new to this site and it seems like it doesn't have anything to private-message someone.

Comment: @GabiG that is not how this site works. This is a public Q&A. There are no private communications (though sometimes questions do spark separate chats). Just post your individual questions, tagged appropriately, and someone may answer them.